# Changing the Sans-Serif Typeface for Body Text in Tufte Class Documents

Tags: tufte

I believe I have reviewed relevant questions, and I have tried many things.  But I cannot find a way to change the sans font in Tufte class docs without introducing other undesired effects, for example compromising some - but not all, mysteriously - of the small caps shapes in other, non-sans regions (eg inside \em}.  I simply wish to replace Helvetica with, for example, Cabin or another bit more "warm" font.  I am using Tufte class because I like the side notes.  MWE (without attempt to change sans typeface) follows.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\newcommand{\morehere}[1]{{\sffamily\small\color{orange}{\bfseries ! #1}}}

\newcommand{\cn}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%

\usepackage{zref-savepos,zref-user}

\newif\ifantilabe
\newcounter{antilabe}
\newcommand{\cd}[1]{%
  \par
  \ifantilabe
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\textsc{#1}.}%
    \zsaveposx{antilabe-\theantilabe-b}%
    \hspace{\numexpr\zposx{antilabe-\theantilabe-a}-\zposx{antilabe-\theantilabe-b}\relax sp}%
    \space
  \else
    \textsc{#1.}%
  \fi
  \antilabefalse
}

\newcommand{\antilabe}{%
  \unskip
  \stepcounter{antilabe}%
  \antilabetrue
  \zsaveposx{antilabe-\theantilabe-a}%
}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setstretch{0.9}

\cd{Bob} I am a bit of verse dialogue.  You see,\\
Modern audiences adore plays in verse,\\
So this play will bring great glory to me\\
\& no doubt fill my soul!\footnote{It is unclear whether \cn{Bob} has a soul.}\antilabe

\cd{Ted} If not your purse.

{\em I am a stage direction.  The music begins.  \cn{Bob} \& \cn{Ted} sing.}

{\sffamily
\cd{Bob} I am a lyric.\\
I am {\em unhappy} to be in the Helvetica typeface.\\
I find it cold \& tight.\\
It breaks my heart.
}

\morehere{I am a note reminding the playwright to finish writing this song.}

\end{document}
```

UPDATE

I'd like to ANSWER this with "misunderstanding \em (& other) environments...not really a Tufte class issue," but I remain confused about the various methods of switching a type family (eg sans serif), & why/how it impacts other things.  Please if anyone knows of a comprehensive discussion of this topic.  The answer might simply be if I stick to best practices with things like \emph{}, then the manner of typeface family selection will not matter (not break my code, because it is not fragile).

Comment: If you compile the above with pdfLaTeX, you can simply place `\usepackage{cabin}` after `\documentclass{tufte-handout}`. The `cabin` package comes with small caps, so this should actually not break any of your styling.

Comment: I tried that, but it broke the small caps inside the \em environment.  I've since fixed by making small caps instances {\rm \textsc{#1}}, but I'm not sure (a) if that's good practice nor (b) why serif! small caps should be broken by adding cabin package.  I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: This is because `\em` resets the font style to default before setting it to italic. You should never use this macro, but rather `\emph{}` or `\textit{}`. Also, please do not use `\rm` or `\bf`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/47927 on this topic.

Comment: Also, note that not all fonts provide italic small-caps.